# How to patch imported function only in chosen class methods?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a class that has two methods. Both of those methods are using a request function imported from another module. How to patch request function only in one of these class methods?

I've looked for such topic but haven't found anything that related.

module foo.py

```py
from module import some_func

class A():
    def func_1():
        return some_func(x)
    def func_2():
        return some_func(y)
```

What I've tried so far:
module test.py

```py
from foo import A

with patch('foo.some_func'):
    A().func_1()
    A().func_2()
```

this would patche both uses of some_func in func_1 and func_2, is that right?

```py
from foo import A

with patch('foo.A.func_1.some_func'):
    A().func_1()
    A().func_2()
```

And this one throws an error that func_1 doesn't have attribute of some_func (which is understandable).

and I'd like to patch the use of some_func only in func_1.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about the reason why you want to do it like this?  For example, what is the code to be tested, how would a test look like, and what role does some_func() play in that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible. The patching works by replacing symbols in a whole module - so when you replace `some_func` in `A`, all instances of `some_func` are patched.

You can get around it by importing `some_func` twice - with two different names

```
from foo import some_func
from foo import some_func as some_func_two
```

Now use `some_func` in `func_1` & `some_func_two` in `func_2`. Now you can patch `some_func` during the test & `func_2` should still use the other method. Though I would advise against it - changing actual code for testing smells like you should refactor your code instead.